# MIPS Infinite loop/error with loading char byte

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to have the user enter either 'Y' to restart the program (branch back to main) or 'N' (branch to end program). I'm reading a single char using syscall opcode 12

```
endCheck:
la $a0, newLine             # Print the newLine
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, endPrompt           # print the Start over message
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 12              # take in char input
syscall
move $t0, $v0

lb $t1, ($t0)               # Load the char byte into t1

beq $t1, 89, main           # Go back to start if they entered 'Y'
bne $t1, 78, endCheck           # Ask the user again because input was not 'N' or 'Y'

li $v0, 10              
syscall
```

I'm getting an error on the lb line. And even when I allocated space of 1 byte on the data segment and read the input as a String of 1 character, I get an infinite loop (it's always branching back to endCheck when it does compile right) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `syscall 12`, the *character itself* is returned in `$v0`. It doesn't give you an address from which to read the character. You can omit the `lb` entirely.

Consequently, you're using `$t1` for the comparisons when you should be using `$t0`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of use to anyone seeing this old post; syscall 12 goes into this infinite loop using spim, but behaves properly using qtspim. spim hasn't been in development since 2010, but I was making some use of it, as it had emacs integration.

Comment: Are you saying there's a bug in plain SPIM when running the loop in the question?  Or is it just a difference in line buffering or something?

Comment: I had the same strange looping issue when trying to read a character. I wrote no branch statement, yet it would loop to the previous label. Things behaved normally when I ran it with qtspim.